# iOS could not load Nib in bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, bundle, nib

I am new to iOS programming and have researched this issue but have not found a solution that works for me. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Code:

```
ViewController *vc =  [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle *** (loaded)' with name 'ViewController''

Comment: have you created a nib (.xib) file named ViewController? By the way, I strongly suggest you to use unique and identifying names for your elements (e.g. MyAppMainFeedViewController) instead of generic names (ViewController).

Comment: Chceck this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6827988/2770572

Comment: Is the view for ViewController in a storyboard? If so, the initWithNibName method won't work, and you will need to get the reference to is from the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the help. i did not create a nib(.xib) file how do i create one if i already created the .h and .m files???

Comment: Go through a beginning iOS book, you're trying to skip too far ahead for your own good.